# Why does this vim search and replace function take multiple "runs" to fully work

Tags: regex, vim

I am using the following vim command: `:v/^\w*sub/s/.*\n//g`

I expect it to get rid of any line that doesn't start with `sub` so I can quickly glance at all the sub headings in my perl script.

It works eventually, but I have to "run" the command 8 times in order for it to only leave the correct lines. Why would it not just work the first time? Not sure it matters but the file is ~1600 lines and it starts by removing ~700 the first time but only the last 2 the final time.

Comment: `:v/^\w*sub/d` meets your requirement.

Comment: Didn’t know about using /d. Much simpler, thanks. Still curious why what I was using doesn’t work as I expected.

Comment: "so I can quickly glance at all the sub headings in my perl script" you don't need to delete half of your buffer for that, use `:g/^\w*sub` for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:help :g` and `:help :v` work in two passes:

1. they put internal marks each matching line,
2. they perform the given action for each marked line.

The problem, here, is that the action you tell Vim to perform on the marked lines messes with the internal marks set by `:v`. Since some of the marks are lost, `:v` is incapable of performing the given action on them.

For comparison, take a look at the outcome of:

```
:v/^\w*sub/s/.*//g
```

which doesn't substitute the newline and thus doesn't mess with `:v`'s internal marks and thus performs the substitution on each line, as expected.

`:help :s` is the wrong tool for the job anyway. As someone already commented, the right tool for the job is `:help :d`:

```
:v/^\w*sub/d
```